# Thread safety using Delegation

Tags: java, multithreading

While going through the **Java Concurrency in Practice** I came across the below code.

Even though `Mutablepoint` is not thread safe, `MonitorVehicleTracker` is Thread safe, since all the invariants that guard the locations Map use Deep copy. My doubt is, it is still possible to change the location of a particular vehicle from the Mutable point by another thread since the coordinates x and y are public, won't it create any concurrent issues? then how can we say that the `MonitorVehicleTracker` is Thread Safe. Can someone please explain how is this Thread Safe.

```
@ThreadSafe
public class MonitorVehicleTracker {
    @GuardedBy("this")
    private final Map<String, MutablePoint> locations;

    public MonitorVehicleTracker(Map<String, MutablePoint> locations) {
        this.locations = deepCopy(locations);
    }

    public synchronized Map<String, MutablePoint> getLocations() {
        return deepCopy(locations);
    }

    public synchronized MutablePoint getLocation(String id) {
        MutablePoint loc = locations.get(id);
        return loc == null ? null : new MutablePoint(loc);
    }

    public synchronized void setLocation(String id, int x, int y) {
        MutablePoint loc = locations.get(id);
        if (loc == null)
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("No such ID: " + id);
        loc.x = x;
        loc.y = y;
    }

    private static Map<String, MutablePoint> deepCopy(Map<String, MutablePoint> m) {
        Map<String, MutablePoint> result = new HashMap<String, MutablePoint>();
        for (String id : m.keySet())
            result.put(id, new MutablePoint(m.get(id)));
        return Collections.unmodifiableMap(result);
    }
}

@NonThreadSafe
public class MutablePoint {
    public int x, y;

    public MutablePoint() {
        x = 0;
        y = 0;
    }

    public MutablePoint(MutablePoint p) {
        this.x = p.x;
        this.y = p.y;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Even though `MutablePoint` contains public variables, all instances of `MutablePoint`s returned by `MotorVehicleTracker` are copies of the instances in the map. Because of this, if a caller obtains an instance of `MutablePoint` and modifies `x` and `y`, those are different from the instances stored in the map in `MotorVehicleTracker`. So `MotorVehicleTracker` is thread safe. `MutablePoint` is not, and it can be used to create race conditions. Those race conditions will not involve `MotorVehicleTracker` because this class only stores copies, and returns copies.

Comment: The only issue with MutablePoint I envision is that some thread might see partially constructed MutablePoint instance. Are there any other concurrency issues here that might arise?